# Mongoose 8.1.1. How to remove undefined fields using findOneAndUpdate

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

How to do for update from not empty fields to undefined and remove them conseguently from resultant object using findOneAndUpdate?

my schema:

```
const testSchema=new Schema({
  _id:Number,
  name:{type:String,default:undefined},
  age:{type:Number},
},{versionKey:false,collection:'tbTest'});
```

my first record:

```
{
  "_id": 2,
  "name": "John",
  "age": 13
}
```

I want update the old record to new value below:

```
{
  "_id": 2,
  "name": "Fabio Di Carlo",
  "age": undefined
}
```

my expected object is:

```
{
  "_id": 2,
  "name": "Fabio Di Carlo"
}
```

while I get this:

```
{
  "_id": 2,
  "name": "Fabio Di Carlo",
  age": 13
}
```

this is my code controller:

```
router.put('/',async(req,res)=>{
  let body=req.body;
  let newTest=await testModel.findOneAndUpdate({_id:testRequest._id},body,{new:true});
  res.json(newTest)
});
```

Why?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `findOneAndUpdate`, you can use `findOneAndReplace` - [Ref](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndReplace/) ,  [mongooseDoc](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#Model.findOneAndReplace())

```
router.put('/',async(req,res)=>{
  let body = req.body;
  let newTest = await testModel.findOneAndReplace({_id:testRequest._id},body);
  res.json(newTest);
});
```

This will replace the **entire document** with new `data` ( here the content of the body, with same `_id` ) of matching `filter`.

Comment: I'm using findOneAndReplace now.
Is it the only solution besides $set and $unset operators on each field?

Comment: Yes, `findOneAndReplace` is the best solution among these for your use case.